# Which part of this code are jade template elements and which are JavaScript elements?

Tags: javascript, pug

What I understand is that the jade template engine has its own templating elements and it also supports some JavaScript. But in the following code I can't distinguish which one is non-JavaScript code (this is [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) + [express.js](http://expressjs.com/)):

This is the view file (index.jade):

```
h1= title
#articles
    - each article in articles
      div.article
        div.created_at= article.created_at
        div.title 
            a(href="/blog/"+article._id.toHexString())!= article.title
        div.body= article.body
```

This is the server file (app.js):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    articleProvider.findAll( function(error,docs){
        res.render('index.jade', { locals: {
            title: 'Blog',
            articles:docs
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Can anyone help me clear this confusion?

Comment: I don't know jade, but none of the code you posted looks like javascript to me.

Comment: second opinion: i don't see any javascript. Although, `article.title` `div.title` are both valid javascript calls, I doubt that they are in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Jade-Lang Readme](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme) has a **Code** section that goes into detail about what is and isn't client side javascript.

Basically if you use code inside your template, and it's not inside a script tag, it will render the output of that javascript before it sends it to the browser. It is still javascript, but it's executed server side. Any javascript inside a script tag is just normal javascript and is sent to the browser like everything else.

---

As for the example you posted, the line:

```
- each article in articles
```

Translates to:

```
for (var article in articles) {
    /* Whatever else is going on in the template */
}
```

Also:

```
a(href="/blog/"+article._id.toHexString())!= article.title
```

Translates (simplified) to

```
"<a href=\"/blog\"" + article._id.toHexString() + ">" + /* Escaped article.title */ + "</a>"
```

But Jade parses and renders the results before it gets sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation!  I've never heard of Jade before, but that looks pretty cool.